# Place horizantal lines for marker size in boostrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing one canvas app to draw and put colors and change marker size, for marker size I have been placing some lines with different sizes(line thick), please check attached image for more clarity[image]

I have been trying below code but it does not look like paint size dropdown

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="markerSizeChange" id="markerSizeList" style="left:390px;background-color: white !important;">
    <li><hr style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"></li><hr style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <li><hr style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"></li><hr style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <li><hr style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"></li><hr style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <li><hr style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **not** to use inline style, as you can overwrite it only using `!important` or jQuery/Javascript. I've modified your code a bit. I've removed the `<hr>`'s because you were overcomplicationg yourself and added a span in `li`'s and added them different `height`.

Working fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ao5b22h/11/)

I hope it helps you:

```js
$('.dropdown li').on('click', function(){
    $('#markerSizeList li.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
    var getHeightOfSelectedElement = $($(this).find('span').height());
    $('#dropdownMenu1').html("<span></span>");
    $('#dropdownMenu1 span').css({ 'height': getHeightOfSelectedElement[0] + 'px', 'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '100%', 'background-color': '#000'})
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu li span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
#el_1 span{
  background: #000;
  height: 2px;
}
#el_2 span{
  background: #000;
  height: 4px;
}
#el_3 span{
  background: #000;
  height: 6px;
}
#el_4 span{
  background: #000;
  height: 8px;
}
.dropdown-menu li:hover{
  background: #CEE5FC;
  border: 1px solid #9BC2E8;
}
.active{
  background: #CEE5FC;
  border: 1px solid #9BC2E8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>

  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="markerSizeChange" id="markerSizeList">
    <li id='el_1'>
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li id='el_2'>
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li id='el_3'>
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li id='el_4'>
      <span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @lonut, Sir it does look good in dropdown, there is no any difference between each line in dropdown

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar, I've made a fiddle. Check my updated answer. Is that what you need? If not, let me know and I'll modify.

Comment: @lonut, Sir this looks fine, can you not place each lines in a box ?? then it looks like paint marker size only right..

Comment: @lonut, Sir, this is fine.. As I expected.. Thank you sir

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar, you're welcome. I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: @lonut, Sir, How can I add active class for click of each li ? Sorry for disturbing you again.. I am trying this $('#markerSizeList li').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); but inline style background color is overriting

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar, see my updated answer and fiddle. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar, I've also made that the selected line to be showed as selected first, instead of dropdown title.

Comment: @lonut, Sir thanks a lot.. You are playing with that anything.. Champ :-)

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTML does not let you style the options of a select box.
You will need a framework to replace the normal HTML Selects.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.. Do you have any idea about frameworks? which is having this type of design

Comment: I use this one myself: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-options

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="markerSizeChange" id="markerSizeList" style="left:390px;background-color: white !important;">
                            <li style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" /></li>
                            <li style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><hr style="height:2px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" /></li>
                            <li style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><hr style="height:4px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" /></li>
                            <li style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><hr style="height:6px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" /></li>
                        </ul>
```

Just change the height of hr in my code for fit with the originals.

Comment: Sir, can we place all lines a box ?